# What is code with updating 'quantity' of product when buyer do order in OpenCart?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart2.x

In moment when buyer do order and locate on:

```
index.php?route=checkout/success
```

page.

I want update quantity of product in another database and another web hosting.

**Question:**

What is file and which string has a code with updating `quantity` of product when buyer do order?

Comment: You can achieve that through the model. AddOrder function.

Comment: @AliZia I did so, but AddOrder function execute on 6th step of order, and buyer can cancel the order on 6th step, but AddOrder function will be execute.

Answer (score 0):

go to : catalog\model\checkout\order.php

Look for **addOrderHistory** function. 
search for // Stock subtraction

> $order_product_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX .
>   "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");